# What is the best way to go about creating/implementing a python script logging system for remote viewing of logs

Tags: python, logging

sorry for the convoluted title. I will try to break it down.

I've recently gotten a Raspberry Pi and I want to build and implement a half decent method to check the status of my python scripts without SSHing. I've already built a little system that has logs added to an HTML file and then the HTML file is localhosted so I can check in without SSHing in to the Raspberry Pi, but currently this method isn't very clean. If I wanted to add more programs to the logging system i would have to copy and paste the code over to the other programs and it would just be really janky.

I am looking for a way to make my logging system able to handle multiple scripts at once and without copy and pasting code. My end goal is to have the process be automatic, I would start a script on the raspberry pi with the logging method built into the script, and my website would automatically add a new button that, when pressed, brings me to the logs of that specific python program.

I'm not asking you to code it for me, I'm asking for the best way to implement this idea. Should I build a module that I can import into all of my files? How would the python script that hosts the website receive the logs?

I realize now as I'm typing this question out that it is really hard to explain or visualize what I am trying to do, I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is a good use case for Python modules. If you already have written the code to write a scripts logs to an HTML file, simply take that code and make it it's own module. Then you can import that module into your other python scripts.

```
# my_logging_module.py
def write_logs(log_data, script_name):
    # your code here
```

and then..

```
# my_script.py
import my_logging_module
my_logging_module.write_logs('foo', 'my_script')
```

You can have your logging module write to a filename based on the script name, and have some other function that generates your "index" page with buttons that link to those other pages. The generation can be done based on a directory listing of files.

Or even better, use something like Nginx to simply serve a static index of the path where your HTML log files live.

Comment: Are there any good resources for learning how to create a module?

Comment: Sure, here is a good start: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-modules-in-python-3

Comment: I've figured most of it out. Down to the logging and method. It works well right now. I run into an issue of hosting the log HTML files though. How would I implement this into a module. How should I go about hosting those HTML files on a local host? Do I build a secondary program that reads the logs directory? How would I even do that? I'm looking for a solution that I could potentially put onto another system without editing anything, like directories.

Comment: Python actually has a built in very simple webserver (not suited for any serious production purposes, but would probably work well for you). You can run it as follows: "python -m http.server 8000" and it will serve up any files in the directory where you run that command on port 8000. For something a little more serious you should look into Nginx